# useContext() is not working in Vite-based react application

Tags: reactjs, vite

I tried using useContext() in my react-app via vite but it gives an error "ReferenceError: AuthContext is not defined"

App.js is given below:

```
/*eslint-disable*/ 

import SomeComponent from './SomeComponent';
import './App.css';

const AuthContext = createContext(null);

function App() {
  
const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState('whatever');

return (
  <AuthContext.Provider value={{someValue}}>
  <SomeComponent/>
  </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App
```

SomeComponent.js is given below:

```
/*eslint-disable*/
import { useContext } from "react";

function SomeComponent() {

    const {someValue} = useContext(AuthContext);

    return (
        <div>
            whatever! this is {someValue}
        </div>
    )
}

export default SomeComponent
```

I ran npm run dev again but it doesn't fix the issue. React-DevTools on Chrome even shows that context is being provided to SomeComponent but still I cannot consume the context via useContext() at all. What error am I making?

Comment: What is `useCustom()`? Do you mean `useContext()`?

Comment: Oops! Yes I meant useContext()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export `AuthContext` from wherever it's defined and import it where you need it

For example

```js
export {
  App as default,
  AuthContext,
};
```

and

```js
import { AuthContext } from "./path/to/App";
```

---

A convenient trick is to encapsulate the context within a custom hook in the same place where it's defined.

For example, in `App.js`

```js
const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export {
  App as default,
  useAuth,
};
```

and in your components

```js
import { useAuth } from "./path/to/App";

function SomeComponent() {

  const { someValue } = useAuth();
```

Comment: Phil thank you for the response. However, even this trick doesn't work. All of the components get undefined as the value of context.

Comment: Phil, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the issue. I used Phil's technique but wrapped AuthContext.Provider around `<App/>` in another component which returned `<App/>`.

Comment: Why not just accept Phil's answer?